# how can i include python 2.7.x in an embedded linux yocto image?

Tags: python-2.7, yocto

Can anyone point me to a tutorial or a reference recipe that includes the right yocto layer to produce a rootfs that has python 2.7 goodies?

I prefer to not use 'dev-pkgs' as an IMAGE_FEATURES because it would include way more than i need.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 9):

Despite [poky already contains](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/python) maybe all what you need regarding python,

[meta-python](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-python/) is the layer you are looking for. It will give you more extensive range of recipes and packages.

Use the [CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL) variable to include the recipes you need.

As the ones you need, take a look at [this recipe](https://github.com/urnenfeld/meta-widde/blob/master/recipes-widde/homeassistant/home-assistant_0.33.4.bb), which has a lot of dependencies on python packages(and python as well).

Notice the number 3 on the recipe name, as you mention python 2.7 you should avoid include any recipe starting with *python3*.

On the other side note that there are many internal of subpackages for example:
python-threading python-multiprocessing python-subprocess python-misc python-netclient which are not external packages but internal parts of python which you may require.

A way to start would be including in your *local.conf* python-core and see during deployment which other modules you might need,

> CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL = "python-core"

Another option is to include **pip**:

> CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL = "python-core python-pip"

Answer (score 0):

I will explain you an easier way to include python than modify local.conf

To include python in your linux system the best form is by hob, when you run hob, and select an image,  you can choose python and python libraries.

To include them you must check edit recipes, and check python and build packages.

After that yocto make a repsitory and python will be included.

Be sure that meta-oe layer is included. If you don't have this layer you can download from this source: https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded and you will see python in meta-oe / meta-oe / recipes-devtools / python /